# Pandas - TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' when trying to find duplicates in a filtered DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicates in a filtered DataFrame. My DataFrame:

```
  Document type   Application number
0       Return    1658
1       Sale      1658
2       Return    1659
3       Sale      1659
4       Return    1659
5       Return    1660
6       Return    1660
```

I need to get duplicated application numbers only in rows with "Return" type of document and write a comment "Duplicate is found" in col of comments in these rows.
Here what I need:

```
  Document type   Application number    Comment
0       Return    1658                  
1       Sale      1658
2       Return    1659                  //Duplicate is found
3       Sale      1659
4       Return    1659                  //Duplicate is found
5       Return    1660                  //Duplicate is found
6       Return    1660                  //Duplicate is found
```

But I get an error TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' when I'm trying to filter the DataFrame.
Here is my code:

```
def check_duplicated_app_nums(df,
                              col_app_num,
                              col_doc_type,
                              col_comments,
                              comment = 'Duplicate is found'):

    mask_doc_type = df[col_doc_type] == 'Return'
    mask_duplicate = df[mask_doc_type].duplicated(subset=col_app_num, keep=False)

    df.loc[mask_duplicate, col_comments] = df.apply(lambda x: '%s//%s' % (x[col_comments], comment), axis=1)
```

It works with this mask_duplicate:

```
mask_duplicate = df.duplicated(subset=col_app_num, keep=False)
```

But in this case it returns:

```
  Document type   Application number    Comment
0       Return    1658                  //Duplicate is found
1       Sale      1658                  //Duplicate is found
2       Return    1659                  //Duplicate is found
3       Sale      1659                  //Duplicate is found
4       Return    1659                  //Duplicate is found
5       Return    1660                  //Duplicate is found
6       Return    1660                  //Duplicate is found
```

How to get duplicates only in rows which I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df.duplicated(subset=['Document type', 'Application number'], keep=False)

df.loc[m, col_comment] = comment
```

As a function:

```
def check_duplicated_app_nums(df,
                              col_app_num,
                              col_doc_type,
                              col_comments,
                              comment = 'Duplicate is found'):

    m = df.duplicated(subset=[col_doc_type, col_app_num], keep=False)

    df.loc[m, col_comment] = f'//{comment}'
    
check_duplicated_app_nums(df, 'Application number', 'Document type', 'Comment')
```

Output:

```
  Document type  Application number               Comment
0        Return                1658                   NaN
1          Sale                1658                   NaN
2        Return                1659  //Duplicate is found
3          Sale                1659                   NaN
4        Return                1659  //Duplicate is found
5        Return                1660  //Duplicate is found
6        Return                1660  //Duplicate is found
```

Comment: OMG, so simply!!! Thank you so much! :)